# Test the series for convergence or divergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

When using the alternating series test, if the limit is not equal to $0$, am I allowed to assume that it's divergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (-1)^n\frac{(3n-1)}{(2n+1)}$$

Let $b_n=\frac{(3n-1)}{(2n+1)}$.

$\lim_{x\to \infty } \frac{3n-1}{2n+1}=\frac{3}{2}\ne0$

Comment: Yes, it diverges.

Comment: It's more or less like your favorite series $-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-\cdots$ at least on its tail

Comment: In your series $\lim (-1)^nb_n$ does not exist. So it is non zero.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to assume: it *is* trivially divergent since the general term of a convergent series tends to $0$.

Indeed if the series $S_n\sum_k=1^n u_k$ tends to $S$, for any $\varepsilon >0$, there's a rank $N$ such that $\lvert S_n-S\rvert<\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. In particular, if $n> N$,
$$\lvert u_n\rvert=\lvert S_n-S_{n-1}\rvert\le\lvert S_n-S\rvert+\lvert S-S_{n-1}\rvert <2\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Why the downvote? This is [the most basic of the necessary conditions for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand) not being satisfied.

Comment: @Clement C: I suppose it's always the same temperamental people which downvote.